# Strange Issue with Paypal Android Integration

Tags: android, paypal

I'm integrating Paypal Payment Gateway with my Android App. I have added this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:+'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
}
```

When I add this `'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.1'`, the application is not able to load my JNI Library.

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("myLibrary");
}
```

If i remove this `'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.1'` it's working well.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: I met the same problem .... any help?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

If you only have jni libs for "armeabi", then if you install the APK to an "armeabi-v7a", only the jni libs in "armeabi-v7a" would be used because PayPal has them.

to fix this:

Method 1. provide as many as possible jni libs for different platforms.

Method 2. use the abiFilters to choose what you have:

```
    ndk {
        abiFilters "x86", "armeabi"
    }
```

Comment: Hello shawn. your answer is correct. is there any sample code to add abiFilters in my gradle file

Comment: It depends on which android building system you are using. For me, in build.gradle, the structure is like this: android {  defaultConfig { ndk { abiFilters "x86", "armeabi" } } }

Answer (score 1):

Had to integrate Unity and PayPal in the same app; Unity worked alright but when I added the PayPal SDK, I could no longer communicate to it and the app crashed.

Following shawn's answer, I came across [this gradle](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-jni/app/build.gradle), and tried adding the productFlavors. My gradle ended up looking like this:

```
productFlavors {
    arm7 {
        // in the future, ndk.abiFilter might also work
        ndk {
            abiFilter 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
    all {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'mips', 'mips64', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
    }
}
```

Because the other flavors didn't work on all devices.